# Inform user on new message in chat app

Tags: android, firebase

I build a chat app and I want to inform my users when they has new message unread like an icon on my home page.
I thought about set a listener on database but this will use some data and I will must set it on all room of each users.
Do you have any idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add ValueEventListener to your DatabaseReference, it will listen to data changes in firebase database, and handle UI action from there.

Comment: Yes i have thought to do this but this  will not weight the bandwith  and slow my app?

Comment: Not really if you are not loading images/movies, just pure text data. And there isnt simple more efficient way to do this.